# Solving exponential equation to find a value in the exponent

Tags: equation-solving

How to find the value of c in the following equation:
`Exp[(-pi*a)/c]+Exp[(-pi*b)/c]=1`

Comment: Please provide more information.  For instance, do you wish a numerical or symbolic solution?  If the former, what are the values of the other symbols?  What code have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps pi is π?

Comment: First simplify:  $-\pi a/c = y$ and $b/a = r$ to get:  $$e^y + e^{ry} = 1.$$

Comment: values of a and b are known and i want a numerical value for c (maybe through iteration)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork kindly elaborate, how to solve beyond this.

Comment: Not a method to *solve* but a method to *pose*.  Please provide this *simplest* relevant question, not one that has irrelevant structure (useless constants, eg.).

Answer (score 7):

It does not look possible to solve this for general `a, b`. But for specific values of these, Mathematica can solve it for `c`

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 expr = Exp[(-Pi*a)/c] + Exp[(-Pi*b)/c] - 1;

 Grid[{{Row[{"equation is ", expr, "==0"}]},
   {Plot[expr, {c, -2, 2}]},
   {N@Solve[expr == 0, c]}
   }]
 ,
 {{a, 1, "a"}, -2, 2, 1/10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 1, "b"}, -2, 2, 1/10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ContinuousAction -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {a, b}
 ]
```

You can experiment more.

Comment: value of a= 1.414 and value of b=3.928. i need a numerical value for c. Please help me accordingly

Comment: @ShikhaSinha  For these numerical values, `Solve` can't solve it. But `FindRoot` can be used. You could try `expr = (Exp[(-Pi*a)/c] + Exp[(-Pi*b)/c] - 1) /. {a -> 1.414, b -> 3.928};
FindRoot[expr == 0, {c, 1}];
FindRoot[expr == 0, {c, -1}];` and so on. Make a plot of `expr` first to see the region where root is located.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want positive solutions, you can do the following:

```
g[a_,b_] := Quiet @ Solve[Exp[(-Pi*a)/c] + Exp[(-Pi*b)/c] == 1 && c>0, c]
```

Examples:

```
g[1, 1]
g[1, Pi]
g[1.414, 3.928]
```

> {{c -> π/Log[2]}}
>
> {{c -> Root[{
>       1 + E^(-π/# + π^2/#) - E^(π^2/#)& , 
>        8.44332255655234342027637371623542201922`20.601814494499823}]}}
>
> {{c -> 11.1144}}

Answer (score 0):

As @David says, first simplify the equation to $e^y + e^{r y}=1$, which leaves only one parameter:

```
f[r_?Positive] := y /. FindRoot[E^y + E^(r y) == 1, {y, -1/r}]
```

where I've used $y\approx -1/r$ as a starting point for the numerical root search. There are no real-valued solutions for $r\le0$.

Plot it to get an idea of the solutions:

```
LogLinearPlot[{f[r], -ProductLog[1/r], -ProductLog[r]/r}, {r, 0, 100}]
```

An approximation for $r\to0$ is found by approximating $e^{r y}\approx1+r y$:

```
Solve[E^y + (1 + r y) == 1, y]
(*    {{y -> -ProductLog[1/r]}}    *)
```

An approximation for $r\to\infty$ is found by approximating $e^y\approx1+y$:

```
Solve[(1 + y) + E^(r y) == 1, y]
(*    {{y -> -ProductLog[r]/r}}    *)
```

[image]